# Adding parameters using deployjava.js from old applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jnlp

I am using deployjava.js to deploy this applet

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script><script> 
    var attributes = {codebase: '/devel/app/webroot/jpainter/applet',code: 'Painter.class', archive:'painter.jar', width:640, height:480} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'plugin2.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
```

The API for the applet says to pass these params (specifically the canvas)

I tried this

```
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script> 
var attributes = {codebase: '/devel/app/webroot/jpainter/applet',code:         'Painter.class', archive:'painter.jar', width:640, height:480} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'plugin2.jnlp', gui:'canvas.gui'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
</script>
```

And clearly that is not correct. What is the correct way to get this working?

JNLP

```
<resources> 
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <jar href="/devel/app/webroot/jpainter/applet/painter.jar"/> 
</resources> 

<applet-desc name="painter" main-class="Painter" width="640" height="480"> 
<param name="plugin2" value="true" />
</applet-desc> 
</jnlp>
```

Comment: *"..clearly that is not correct."*  For the benefit of those of us who think it is as clear as mud.  Why is that not correct?  What is the output?  BTW - the `applet-desc` element requires a `documentBase` attribute.  Be sure to validate the JNLP with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) (& the HTML with the [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/)).

Comment: I was improperly and unnesseraly passing the 'jnlp' parameter. I already called the painter.jar via the attributes. When I called the jnlp using the parameters it merely returned the jnlp. I posted my final solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon this in the future, when you call the attribute and give it the location of your .jar file, it isn't needed to also reference the jnlp.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var attributes = {name: 'painter', codebase: BASE_DIR + '/app/webroot/jpainter/applet',code: 'Painter.class', archive:'painter.jar', width:742, height:262} ; 
var parameters = {gui:'canvas.gui', image_width:'740', image_height:'260', stroke:'solid3'};
var version = '1.6' ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```